Java grab all key value pairs from a Map that contains a substring of a word within a key
I have the following Map.
    Map<String, Object> requestParam = new HashMap<>();

    requestParam.put("name", "testing123");
    requestParam.put("phoneNumber", "1231231234");
    requestParam.put("feedback.1", true);
    requestParam.put("feedback.2", true);
    requestParam.put("feedback.3", false);
    requestParam.put("feedback.4", true);
    requestParam.put("feedback.5", true);
    requestParam.put("feedback.6", false);

I need to go thorugh this Map and find all of the keys with the "feedback" name in them, and then pull out the number next to it where the value is true.
For example, my final result should contain.
[1, 2, 4, 5]
Can I do this easily?
I found a solution doing it like this:
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : requestParam.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getKey().startsWith("feedback")) {
            String[] splitKey = e.getKey().split("\\.");
            boolean value = (boolean) e.getValue();
            if (value) {
                System.out.println(splitKey[1]);
            }

        }
    }

Is there a better way? The requestParam map could contain hundreds of entries...
NEW CHANGE:
    var feedBackNos = requestParam
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith("feedback."))
            .filter(entry -> (entry.getValue() instanceof Boolean && (Boolean) entry.getValue()))
            .map(mapEntry -> mapEntry.getKey().substring(9));


    feedBackNos.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));


You can iterate over or stream the entry set of that map and apply filters as needed. It's not complicated - what did you try so far?

see above edit. @Thomas

With HashMap there is not really a faster option as there is no way to generate proper hashes from partial keys and thus you'd have to look at every entry. Using TreeMap you could do a binary search for all the entries whose key is between "feedback." and some upper limit (e.g. "feedback_.") - But having to convert from HashMap to TreeMap first will incur some cost so this would only be faster if you'd use TreeMap in the first place - which will have worse performance on other operations.

AFAIK Trie datastructures are better candidates for performance in these cases. In case you can include a dependency on a Trie implementation (for example Apache Commons Collections) in your project, then I would use a PatriciaTrie instead of a Map and then traverse all entries of prefixMap("feedback.").

Your example implies a feedback.n key always refers to a boolean value.  If so, no need to check that the value is an instance of boolean, just cast it.  And you can combine the filters into one.  If this in not correct, please update your question to include a more diverse map.  Otherwise we can only guess what the actual requirements are.

Here is one way to do it.  You are probably worrying about speed prematurely. Wait until the program is done before worrying about performance.  If your approach works, stick with it.
You didn't specify:

returning a list or array so I chose array.
converting to an int or leave as a string so I left as a string.
your example implied "feedback" is always at the beginning of the key. If not, please provide a more diverse example.

Procedure.

stream entrySet
filter on the key and value
extract the number and return in an array.

String[] results = requestParam.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith("feedback")
                        && (Boolean) e.getValue())
            .map(e -> e.getKey().split("\\.")[1])
            .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));

prints
[2, 1, 4, 5]



Just minor suggestions as possible improvements: you can use startsWith("feedback.") (with dot character) rather than startsWith("feedback") (without dot) so as to guarantee the split will end up with at least 2 entries. You can also check that e.getValue() is Boolean before the cast (because requestParam is a Map<String, Object>).

@gthanop Thanks but all my assumptions were based on the example provided.  I have no reason to add extra complexity to the solution unless the OP modifies their constraints on the map contents. Since I am assuming a boolean for feedback values and filtering first, I will not do an erroneous cast to boolean.

Yes indeed, it's not clearly stated if there are assumptions about the contents of the Map, my bad.

@gthanop  No, it's not your bad.  Good suggestions!!! but look at the OP's imperative solution and see the assumptions the OP made of their own data.

Ok, I now understand that your assumptions are the exact same as the OP's assumptions (based on their initial posted solution).

With a HashMap, you can do it easily, but not efficiently. Let me put everyone else's answer into a single one with all the mistakes corrected.
private final String FEEDBACK_PREFIX = "feedback.";

...

List<String> results = requestParam.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith(FEEDBACK_PREFIX))
    .filter(e -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(e.getValue()))
    .map(e -> e.getKey())
    .map(k -> k.substring(FEEDBACK_PREFIX.length())
    .toList();

Use a constant to describe your prefix with an undestandable name. This provides us a quick access to the prefix length when we need it in substring.
Use startsWith() instead of contains because it guards against keys that have "feedback" elsewhere in the string. You may not have it now, but you may have later, this is called defensive programming.
Use the whole "feedback." as the prefix, with the dot. This is again defensive programming that guards against mistakes where there is a "feedback" prefix that does not match the pattern.
Filter boolean values using Boolean.TRUE.equals as it does the instanceof test internally.
Put each logical and to a separate filter to make the code more readable. Same with map.
Use substring instead of split + array indexing, because at this point the prefix is irrelevant with regards to the result and substring is more efficient.

I edited my oringal post with what I tried and it worked, but im not 100% sure this would be the fastest/best solution

Using Stream API.
var feedBackNos = results
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith("feedback") &&
                    entry.getValue() instanceof Boolean)
            .map(mapEntry -> mapEntry.getKey().split(".//")[1]).toList();


This is pretty good, but do not use "contains(...)", use "startsWith(...)" as it only checks the prefix. Also compare to "feedback." with a dot to guarantee the correct prefix. Don't put multiple and statements into a single filter, use separate filters instead. You forgot to filter in only the entries where the value is true. And use "substring(...)" instead of "split(...)" because the prefix is not interesting here. And you don't need to use instanceof, just use "Boolean.TRUE.equals(...)".

It also only takes values if the corresponding entry is true, so you might change your instanceof tofilter(entry.getValue() instanceof Boolean && (Boolean) entry.getValue()).

thanks for all the tips... i updated my question with new code.
